# Error with Double-Dabble decoder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm using a Binary to BCD system using [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHTFvZiRj8E) double-dabble decoding device. It all seems pretty good, but it doesn't work properly. If you are unfamiliar with double-dabble, it should take an input, and if it's higher than 4, add 3. I've seen this device used in another video, but this one doesn't work 100% correctly.

Even after downloading the schematic and opening it in CircuitSimulator, putting in a 5 gives a 7, not an 8 like expected:

[image: circuitsim screenshot]

Anyone good enough to identify the problem?

Comment: What does it give as output for each input from 0 up? The image above isn't complete so it isn't necessarily sufficient to help you. Maybe it's not _adding_ three, but turning on the _bits_ for three?

Comment: That diagram doesn't look complete; some of the lines terminate oddly as if there is an additional layer which isn't shown.  Any chance you can post the world file?  It might be easier to decipher "hands-on", as it were.

Comment: You're correct, it isn't complete. Here's the full schematic if you want to look at it: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2298862/Add-3%20Module.schematic

Answer (score 1):

You have to note 3 things:

- Every next unit has to be one farther to the left than the other (1 goes to 2, 2 goes to 4 and 4 goes to 8)
- Every third next unit needs a follow neighbor (Output 8 goes to Input of next potence of 10 [Output 8 from *ones* goes to Input 1 from *units*, Output 8 from *units* goes to Input 1 from *hundreds*])
- The One mustn't be shifted, so its line will go straight on.

Comment: -1: If you're going to answer, do it.  Don't just reference your YouTube account.

Comment: sorry, but whatever you could write in an email you could also write here, no? Just click on edit and show what you got. Otherwise this is just "Improve your golf score while earning money, ask me how" spam

Comment: I'm sorry, but this topic is so complex is really difficult to explain.

But OK I'll give it a try:

If u wanna use this algorithm, u have to note 3 things:
-Every next unit has to be shiften one to the left (1 goes to 2, 2 goes to 4 and 4 goes to 8)
-Every third next unit needs a follow neighbor (Output 8 goes to Input of next potence of 10 [Output 8 from ONES goes to Input 1 from UNITS, Output 8 from UNITS goes to Input 1 from HUNDRETS])
-The One mustn't be shifted, so this line will go straight on

That's all u have to mind, but if u still not understand, message me on Youtube (OK? :])

Comment: I see you're new to this site, so welcome! You can edit old posts by clicking on "edit". If you put your comment into your answer, I'll remove my downvote (though for an upvote at least some screenshot, diagram or even video would be more helpful). By the way, if you want to make sure someone notices you replied to their comment, you can write @username (Tab completion works) in your comment

Comment: And btw it's not sure that whatever i could write in an email i could write here too because here i have to limit myelf to 550 characters i think, but i could (or maybe have to) write more than 1000 words ;) And no it's no spam, i can explain this fact to everyone, but maybe not here in this limited comment :)

Comment: I'm not sure if a video would be more helpful... I wanted to make a video for this topic but in connection with another and this would be:1) in two weeks 2) in german (because i'm german :D) But hey, if you want me to make this video i will do it in a few days :)

Comment: @[_](http://oh.for.crying.out.loud)TheUnSpeed that's why you should click on edit below your post instead of sending new "comments", there is no such limitation then. But 1) if you do a video, that will certainly be helpful :) and 2) falls Du Probleme beim Übersetzen hast, schreib einfach eine grobe Übersetzung (oder zu Not auf deutsch), andere Benutzer können das dann immer noch in "perfektes" Englisch editieren - schreib hier einfach nen Kommentar der mit @Tobias anfängt dann schau ich's mir an

Comment: @Tobias OK, i'll do the video within a few days :) btw i've registered to this community because i think i like it :D BUT (and that's important) you have got really REALLY annoying rules for creating a password -.- Thats so unnecessary :D

Comment: @TheUnSpeed Welcome! I've edited your comment into the answer - the answer area has silly high character limits, so don't worry about it! Feel free to expand on it with the 'edit' button. If you want to embed a youtube video in your answer, simply put a naked link to it in the answer body.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to determine the input and output, then place redstone torches where the redstone ends anywhere else besides in and out. Maybe that will work?

Comment: I counted the spots that the redstone ends: there are 12 So if this goes up to ten then 2 should be inputs and outputs